# How do I get a solver (problem) in an SMTLIB format using the Z3 Python API?

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I would like to print the SMTLIB string of a problem. For example to save a constructed problem to a file, run other solvers on it, etc.

I know of the functions `sexpr()` and `to_smt2()` but the latter behaves in unexpected ways. In particular it does not add function definitions. After the following script:

```
solv = z3.Solver()
n = z3.Int("n")
f = z3.RecFunction("f", [z3.IntSort(), z3.IntSort()])
z3.RecAddDefinition(f, n, n * 5 )
solv.add(f(2) == 10)
```

Now `sexpr()` returns

```
(define-funs-rec ( ( f ((x!1 Int)) Int)) ( (* x!1 5)))
(assert (= ((_ f 0) 2) 10))
```

lacking for example `set-info` and `check-sat` commands. `to_smt2()` on the other hand returns

```
(set-info :status unknown)
(assert (= ((_ f 0) 2) 10)) 
(check-sat)
```

print the set-info/check-sat which is what I would expect but does not include the function definitions for `f` for example. How can I obtain an SMTLIB2 string that includes the definitions etc. as well as check-sat/set-info etc. commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t any. Just use `sexpr` and add the additional bits yourself.